# How to make variable of calling function known to called function (not as function argument)

Tags: r

Optimization in `R` often works by having a function that returns the objective function value evaluated at some point of the candidate parameter space, for instance

```
f=function(x) x[1]**2+x[2]**2
```

Then the optimal vector `x` is usually found by

```
x_opt=somepkg::optim(f,xstart,params) #xstart may be the starting point
```

For good reasons, most packages allow `f` to have additional parameters `params` ***not*** to be optimized (by using the ellipsis `...` in the optimization function `somepkg::optim`). See, for instance, `DEOptim`.
So, if I had

```
f=function(x,a) x[1]**2+x[2]**2+a*x[1]
```

I would call

```
x_opt=somepkg::optim(f,xstart,a=1)
```

Now, I have encountered a package (`rBayesianOptimization`) that uses the ellipsis to pass parameters on to some function of a dependency package (`GPfit`) but *not to* `f`. Therefore, the question arises how to make `a` known to `f`...

Below is a minimal example that shows how I was able to get around the missing ellipsis. However, I have the feeling that my method can introduce some serious pitfalls I am not yet aware of. Please give me pointers on how this is done properly.

```
library(rBayesianOptimization)

Test_Fun <- function(x) {
  #hacky way of finding 'a' from the calling function
  #n=6 was "empirically" determined
  a=get("a",envir=parent.frame(n=6))
  list(Score = exp(-a*(x - 2)^2) + exp(-(x - 6)^2/10) + 1/ (x^2 + 1),
       Pred = 0)
}

Do_Opt=function () {
  #it's a requirement of mine that BayesianOptimization is called from Do_Opt
  a=2

  OPT_Res <- BayesianOptimization(Test_Fun,
                                  bounds = list(x = c(1, 3)),
                                  init_points = 2, n_iter = 1,
                                  acq = "ucb", kappa = 2.576, eps = 0.0,
                                  verbose = FALSE)
}

Do_Opt()
```

Comment: try defining Test_Fun within Do_Opt (below a=2): "Lexical scoping looks up symbol values based on how functions were nested when they were created, not how they are nested when they are called. " (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html)

Comment: though if you need to have access to Test_Fun from outside Do_Opt, this is not optimal..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the additioanl parameters in a "constructor function" like so:

```
getTestFun <- function(a) {

  Test_Fun <- function(x) {
   list(Score = exp(-a*(x - 2)^2) + exp(-(x - 6)^2/10) + 1/ (x^2 + 1),
   Pred = 0)
  }

  Test_Fun

}
```

You can then do:

```
Do_Opt=function () {

  a=2
  Test_Fun <- getTestFun(a)

  OPT_Res <- BayesianOptimization(Test_Fun,
                                  bounds = list(x = c(1, 3)),
                                  init_points = 2, n_iter = 1,
                                  acq = "ucb", kappa = 2.576, eps = 0.0,
                                  verbose = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This works! After reading the webpage from @friep 's comment, it seems as if such constructions run under the name 'closures'. Learned something new...

Comment: Glad I could help :)